# How to make webjars version agnostic in spring mvc

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, webjars

I have followed the documentation on their website as described [here](http://www.webjars.org/documentation)

First of all I added the required path

`<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>`

then I created a controller with the following

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/webjarslocator/{webjar}/**")
public ResponseEntity locateWebjarAsset(@PathVariable String webjar, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        String mvcPrefix = "/webjarslocator/" + webjar + "/"; // This prefix must match the mapping path!
        String mvcPath = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        String fullPath = assetLocator.getFullPath(webjar, mvcPath.substring(mvcPrefix.length()));
        return new ResponseEntity(new ClassPathResource(fullPath), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Few dependencies were missing so I added in maven the following pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

The above will import the following

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
```

None of these has been imported from the external jar.

The error is: `assetLocator cannot be resolved`

EDIT: It could be that I need to create a filter rather than put it in a controller. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: And where did you define `assetLocator`?

Comment: @zeroflagL Nowhere, my question is about how to define one

Comment: `new WebJarAssetLocator()` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot I was trying `new AssetLocator()` which was not resolved

Comment: Please answer this question and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/webjars/webjars-locator) is quite sparse, but you can create an instance of an asset locator with `new WebJarAssetLocator()`.

Comment: I'd love a pull request to improve these docs: https://github.com/webjars/webjars/blob/master/app/views/documentation.scala.html#L341-L431

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, considering more recent versions of WebJar, in a similar vein for anyone else who stumbles upon this question. Using `org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil#locate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` (which, in-turn, uses `org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator#getFullPath(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`) accepts the WebJar name (which acts as a scope) and the file without needing to provide a full path that necessitates including the version.